# Scrolling scrollview based on pan gesture translation

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I want to know how to convert pan gesture **y** translation to equivalent of a scrollview content **y** offset.

So in this I can scroll my scrollview through pan gesture translation reproducing the same effect of a natural scrollview scrolling.

```
let scrollYOffset: CGFloat = panGesture.translation(in: view).y
```

When I did this it resulted in a very jerky scrolling as the scrollYOffset value changed from 0 to 54 and then 124 on dragging.

What I want is a smooth and natural scrolling of a scrollview using pan gesture.

You may ask why I am not using the natural scrollview and its delegate -

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
```

and the answer is I am trying to build an app where a user can drag an object on the screen and the scrollview behind it should scroll by that much.

Can anyone help me in converting the pan gesture **y** translation into scrollview **y** content offset.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Not really clear what you're trying to do... Do you have, for example, a horizontal scroll view, and as you drag an object left-right you want the scroll view content to scroll? So, drag the object all the way left and you see the beginning of the scroll content... drag all the way right and see the end of the scroll content?

Comment: Yes exactly this is what needed

Answer (score 2):

Method `translation:` returns a difference between a previous and current iterations, so you should add the translation to the existing result, something like this.

```
     @objc private func handleGesture(panGestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
         switch panGestureRecognizer.state {
         case .begin:
            break
         case .changed:
            let translation = panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: self.view)
            panGestureRecognizer.setTranslation(.zero, in: self.view)

            let newYOffset = currentOffset + translation.y
         case .ended:
            break
         }
     }
```

Comment: Interesting solution, thank. But scroll bouncing not working in that case.

Answer (score 0):

There are various methods to get a "smooth draggable view" --- but, for your purpose, a possible option would be to use a `UISlider`:

[image]

If desired, you can change the appearance of the slider by setting the thumb and track images.

Example code (used for that screen-cap):

```
class SliderScrollViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    
    let scrollView: UIScrollView = UIScrollView()
    let slider: UISlider = UISlider()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        [scrollView, slider].forEach {
            view.addSubview($0)
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }

        // horizontal stack view to hold scroll content
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.distribution = .fillEqually
        stack.spacing = 8
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // add 20 views to the stack view for horizontal scrolling
        for i in 1...20 {
            let v = UILabel()
            v.textAlignment = .center
            v.backgroundColor = .yellow
            v.text = "View \(i)"
            stack.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }
        stack.arrangedSubviews.first?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
        scrollView.addSubview(stack)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        let svCLG = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        let svFLG = scrollView.frameLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120.0),
            
            slider.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            slider.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            slider.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
            stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: svCLG.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: svCLG.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: svCLG.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: svCLG.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),

            stack.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: svFLG.heightAnchor, constant: -16.0),
            
        ])
        
        slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.sliderChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        
        // so we can see the frame of the scroll view
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .green
        
        // set scrollView delegate
        scrollView.delegate = self
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        // we need to update the slider position when scroll view is manually scrolled
        let w = scrollView.contentSize.width - scrollView.frame.size.width
        let pct = scrollView.contentOffset.x / w
        slider.value = Float(pct)
    }

    @objc func sliderChanged(_ sender: UISlider) -> Void {
        // set scroll view's content offset x based on position of slider
        let w = scrollView.contentSize.width - scrollView.frame.size.width
        let x = w * CGFloat(sender.value)
        scrollView.contentOffset.x = x
    }
    
}
```

---

**Edit**

Thought I'd play around with this a bit more... this example grabs the scroll view's content as a `UIImage`, uses that for a "background" image behind the slider, and creates an outlined image for the slider's thumb:

[image]

[image]

Complete code:

```
class SliderScrollViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    
    let scrollView: UIScrollView = UIScrollView()
    let scrollContentView: UIView = UIView()
    let slider: UISlider = UISlider()
    let sliderBKG: UIImageView = UIImageView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        [scrollView, sliderBKG, slider].forEach {
            view.addSubview($0)
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        
        // horizontal stack view to hold scroll content
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.distribution = .fillEqually
        stack.spacing = 8
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        // add 20 views to the stack view for horizontal scrolling
        for i in 1...20 {
            let v = UILabel()
            v.textAlignment = .center
            v.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0 - (CGFloat(i) * 0.05), alpha: 1.0)
            v.text = "View \(i)"
            stack.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }
        stack.arrangedSubviews.first?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
        
        scrollContentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollContentView.addSubview(stack)
        scrollView.addSubview(scrollContentView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        let svCLG = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        let svFLG = scrollView.frameLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120.0),
            
            slider.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            slider.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            slider.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            slider.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0),
            
            sliderBKG.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: slider.topAnchor, constant: 6.0),
            sliderBKG.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: slider.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            sliderBKG.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: slider.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            sliderBKG.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: slider.bottomAnchor, constant: -6.0),
            
            scrollContentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: svCLG.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            scrollContentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: svCLG.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            scrollContentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: svCLG.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            scrollContentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: svCLG.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            scrollContentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: svFLG.heightAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollContentView.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollContentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollContentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollContentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            
        ])
        
        slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.sliderChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        
        // set slider images to clear images
        slider.setThumbImage(UIImage(), for: [])
        slider.setMinimumTrackImage(UIImage(), for: [])
        slider.setMaximumTrackImage(UIImage(), for: [])
        
        // so we can see the frame of the scroll view
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .green
        scrollContentView.backgroundColor = .orange
        
        // set scrollView delegate
        scrollView.delegate = self
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        // after view has appeared (so we know auto-layout has finished)
        // grab the content of the scroll view as a UIImage
        let img = scvSnapshot()
        // set it to the "background" image view behind the slider
        sliderBKG.image = img
        updateThumbImage()
    }
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { _ in
        }, completion: {
            _ in
            self.updateThumbImage()
        })
    }
    func updateThumbImage() -> Void {
        // generate a proportional width bordered clear image
        let w = self.scrollView.frame.width * (self.scrollView.frame.width / self.scrollView.contentSize.width)
        let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: w, height: 40.0))
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: rect.size)
        let img = renderer.image { rc in
            rc.cgContext.setFillColor(UIColor.clear.cgColor)
            rc.cgContext.setStrokeColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
            rc.cgContext.setLineWidth(2)
            rc.cgContext.addRect(rect)
            rc.cgContext.drawPath(using: .fillStroke)
        }
        // set the slider's custom thumb image
        self.slider.setThumbImage(img, for: [])
    }
    func scvSnapshot() -> UIImage {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: scrollContentView.bounds)
        return renderer.image { rendererContext in
            scrollContentView.layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
        }
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        // we need to update the slider position when scroll view is manually scrolled
        let w = scrollView.contentSize.width - scrollView.frame.size.width
        let pct = scrollView.contentOffset.x / w
        slider.value = Float(pct)
    }
    
    @objc func sliderChanged(_ sender: UISlider) -> Void {
        // set scroll view's content offset x based on position of slider
        let w = scrollView.contentSize.width - scrollView.frame.size.width
        let x = w * CGFloat(sender.value)
        scrollView.contentOffset.x = x
    }
    
}
```